# Kotlin not making request Volley - android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to "dynamically" create CardView and then fill TextView with data from an API call. The thing is, to me it seems like the request is not getting called.

I created an adapter class based on [Create dynamically lists with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) which is working fine and I am adding as many windows as needed. And then in the MainActivity, I am trying to do an API request with Volley. Before I created manually TextView and fed the results manually into it - which worked fine. But now with this dynamically created CardView nothing is happening. Could anyone try to guide me please?

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //    private var message: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.jsonParse)

    lateinit var weatherRV: RecyclerView
    lateinit var weatherModelArray: ArrayList<WeatherViewModel>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        weatherRV = findViewById(R.id.mainView)

        weatherModelArray = ArrayList()


        val model1 = WeatherViewModel("Open weather", "")
        val model2 = WeatherViewModel("Yr.no", "")

        weatherModelArray.add(model1)
        weatherModelArray.add(model2)

        val weatherAdapter = WeatherAdapter(this, weatherModelArray)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        weatherRV.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        weatherRV.adapter = weatherAdapter

        apICall(this@MainActivity, model1)
    }

}
```

apiCall:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
internal fun apICall(context: Context, jsonView: WeatherViewModel) {
    var lat: Double? = null
    var lon: Double? = null
    var url: String? = null
    val apiKey: String = "XXXX"

    lat = YYY.Y
    lon = YYY.Y
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric&exclude=minutely,hourly"
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

    val gsonPretty = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create() 
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        {response ->
            val gson = Gson()
            val openJSON = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), OpenWeatherJSON::class.java)
            val prettyJsonString = gsonPretty.toJson(openJSON)
            try {
                val dt = openJSON.daily[0].dt
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                val date = Date(dt * 1000) //                snackbar.dismiss()

                sdf.format(date) //                jsonView.apiResult = sdf.format(date) //                jsonView.apiResult.append("\n")
                jsonView.apiResult = openJSON.daily[0].temp.toString()
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                jsonView.apiResult = e.toString()
            }
        },
        {
            jsonView.apiResult = "Error"
        })

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest) }
```

Now in the image below you can see, that Result1 is not getting changed into the request response. I can change it with `jsonView.text = "something"` outside the stringRequest
[image: Result1 empty]

Update1:

```
class WeatherAdapter(context: Context, weatherModelArray: ArrayList<WeatherViewModel>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val weatherModelArray: ArrayList<WeatherViewModel>

    // Constructor
    init {
        this.weatherModelArray = weatherModelArray
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = weatherModelArray[position]
        holder.apiName.text = model.apiName
        holder.apiResult.text = model.apiResult

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return weatherModelArray.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val apiName: TextView
        val apiResult: TextView

        init {
            apiName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idApiName)
            apiResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idApiResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing the displayed data? What is your `WeatherAdapter` doing with the `apiResult` attribute?

Comment: @TylerV thank you for the reply, anyway, I have updated the code above, WeatherAdapter is just setting the text of the TextView (for now). I tried using ```weatherAdapter.notifyDataseChanged()``` after ```apiCall()``` but nothing has changed

Comment: You would have to call `notifyDataSetChange`  inside your response code (right after you update the data with `jsonView.apiResult = something`) - not after `apiCall`. The response is asynchronous, so the code inside your result callback does not run immediately.

Comment: @TylerV I see, yes, that seems to work, I added the adapter into apiCall class ```internal fun apICall(context: Context, jsonView: WeatherViewModel, weatherAdapter: WeatherAdapter)``` and then called ```weatherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()``` and now I am getting the result as expected. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the RecyclerView adapter that the data has changed *after* you change the data. This means calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from within the callback. That would look something like this:

```kotlin
internal fun apICall(context: Context, jsonView: WeatherViewModel, adapter: WeatherAdapter) {
    //...
    
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        {response ->
            //...
            jsonView.apiResult = openJSON.daily[0].temp.toString()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        },
        {
            jsonView.apiResult = "Error"
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest) 
}
```

Comment: Just a question, is this the "official" approach? Because IntelliJ is telling me, that using ```notifyDatasetChanged()``` is a "last resort"

Comment: It is an expensive operation since it redraws the whole list. If you know the position of the item in question you can call a different notify method (`notifyItemChanged(position)`), or you can make your adapter inherit from `ListAdapter` and use the `submitList` option. If neither of those is feasible or something you want to implement, then `notifyDataSetChanged()` is still your easiest approach. As long as the list isn't terribly long it won't be a big cost.